# PROBLEMA WORDPRESS HTTP Y HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, http, https

El problema que tengo en wordpress es que mi página que tiene certificado SSL instalado y también el pluggin Really Simple SSL activado sin errores, al ingresar por http sale un error y no lo redirecciona al https y al ingresar directamente por https no tengo error alguno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

- Puede ser que tu .htaccess no este redireccionando. prueba hacer esto.

  `RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

aqui te dejo un link util https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/215747758-Forzar-tu-sitio-a-cargar-de-forma-segura-con-un-archivo-htaccess

- si tienes acceso a tu servidor. revisa que el virtual host redireccione del puerto 80 que es el http al puerto 443 https.

  `<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  Redirect permanent /secure https://yourdomain.com/secure
  </VirtualHost>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName www.yourdomain.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  SSLEngine On
  </VirtualHost>`

  te dejo un enlace https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9821/38/apache-redirect-to-https

Comment: Exacto. Para qué usar un plugin que sólo es insertar unas cuantas líneas en un archivo de configuración?